# how chat servers communicate in a server farm?

Tags: sockets, networking, architecture, network-programming, chat

I am developing a chat application that consist of the following:

1) `aws` elastic `tcp` load balancer.

2) server farm that consists of multiple servers that must communicate with each 
   other ( S2S ).

3) the server is implemented in `go`.

the main concerns here are how the servers will communicate with each others given the following :

1) how to know which user is located in which server ?

2) when two users chat one of them may disconnect and reconnect to different 
   server how to know which server he is connected to again ?

**NOTE::**

1) I will not use the xmpp servers ever It's losing It's ground and I want to 
   develop the server myself with sockets.

2) I have a different server design that will have less payload than the xmpp 
   payload.

2) I have enough time to develop even If It will take so long.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too broad of a question for stackoverflow. Please read [what topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @JamesKPolk i edited it to smaller narrower one

Comment: While I cannot know the specific reason for the votes, if you hover over the down arrow, it will tell you the default reason: "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_."

Comment: Your question is _"How do I design a scalable chat protocol"_, which is simply too broad to answer. Stack Overflow is more suited towards implementation problems, but you're still in the design phase.

Comment: @CodeCaster ok should I edit it to a more specefic one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of what [AWS SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) is designed for.